# Yii - How to implement curly brackets in your module/models?

Tags: yii

I must be missing something here, because I have the following in my config/main.php:

```
'db'=>array(
  ...some config...
  'tablePrefix' => 'appname_'
  ...more config...
),
```

Then I created a new module (testModule) and have listed the table name there as 'test_user':

```
public $userTable = '{{test_user}}';
```

In my DB migration script I create the mysql table like so:

```
$this->createTable(Yii::app()->getModule('test')->userTable, array(
  "id" => "pk",
  "username" => "varchar(20) NOT NULL",
  "password" => "varchar(128) NOT NULL",
  "email" => "varchar(128) NOT NULL",
  "active" => "varchar(128) NOT NULL",
  "created" => "int(10) NOT NULL",
  "updated" => "int(10) NOT NULL",
));
```

BUT, when I run the migration script, the table name in the DB is {{test_user}}, when what I expected was 'appname_test_user'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your console config file. You should have there the same 'tablePrefix' in 'db' section as in main.php (or where you store configuration of web app db). Running migrations, you execute `yiic` and console application config is used.

To avoid that confusion in future, you can move all settings of db component into another config file (ex `config/db.php`). Then you can include it in both `config/console.php` and `config/main.php` this way:

```
//..
'db'=>require('db.php'),
//..
```

Comment: Of course!  Nice call...I knew it had to be something stupid that I was missing.  Thanks again.